# iOS schedule push notifications

Tags: ios, swift

I want to schedule push notifications, I mean that my app can send notifications to users every certain time interval, for example every 24 hours sends a notification.
How can I do this? Do I have to use a server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDK like https://onesignal.com/ (REST architecture) or create your own simple CRON based server. It's up to you.

Or one more possibility (not free) is to use [Task Scheduling on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine). Google App Engine provides a Cron service. Using this service for scheduling and Google Cloud Pub/Sub for distributed messaging, you can build an application to reliably schedule tasks across a fleet of Compute Engine instances.